# Regex to match a string not followed by some string

Tags: regex

I have a string block as below

```
1. While #EngineSpeed$b4tgup#
2. While #AcceleratorPedal$desddd# <=2
3. While #AcceleratorPeda@$desddd# <=2
4. While #AcceleratorPe#al$desddd# <=2
5. While #AcceleratorP@dal$desddd# <=2
6. While #AcceleratorPeda l$desddd# <=2
7. 设置 #AcceleratorPedal$y6qs8m#=@AcceleratorPedal+0.06
8. 设置 #WaitStart$jhx0vu#=11
9. 设置 #WaitStart$jhx0vu#^11
10. 设置 #WaitStart$jhx0vu#_11
11. 设置 #WaitStart$jhx0vu#-11
12. 设置 #AcceleratorQuora$yd6ba3#=1
13. 设置 #AcceleratorQuora$yd6bd3#=1
14.
15. Check #EnginePower#
16. While #EngineSpeed
17. set #WaitStart
18. set #WaitStart<13
19. set #WaitStart<=13
20. set #WaitStart <= 13
```

Now I want to have a regex to match a substring starts with `#` but not followed by `#` or not followed by a substring like this `$\w{6}#`.

So in the string block above only line 16,17,18,19,20 match,in line 16 the result is **#EngineSpeed**,in line 17 the result is **#WaitStart**,the others are not match, in line 20 ,the result is also **#WaitStart**, it followed by `<= 13`,not followed by `#` or `$\w{6}#`,so it's also match!

For example,in line 15 the string is **Check #EnginePower#**,it starts with `#`,but it followed by `#`,in line 13 the string is **设置 #AcceleratorQuora$yd6bd3#=1**,it starts with `#`,but followed by a substring like `$\w{6}#`.

I have wrote a regex like this `#\w+(?<!#|$\w{6}#)`,but the test result in RegexBuddy is shown in the picture below,almost every line is match,it doesn't meet my requirement,how can I can modify the regex? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I believe that OP didn't express his thoughts well. Title is misleading. Vote to reopen.

Comment: Oh my god,this guys don't read my questions carefully and they mark it as a duplicate question careless!

Comment: Or [`#[^\W_]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/rN3mP9/2)

Comment: Why should line 17 match start with **set** ? You said, you want strings that start with `#`. So, why is it different than line 16? What's the rule that distinguishes between these two?

Comment: @TamasRev ,I said a string not a line,so the substring in line 17 is okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From all the strings above you want to match

> 16. While **#EngineSpeed**
> 17. set **#WaitStart**
> 18. set **#WaitStart**<13
> 19. set **#WaitStart**<=13
> 20. set **#WaitStart** <= 13

You can use

```
(?<=\s)#\w+(?!.*[@$#])
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN3mP9/8)

**Details**:

- `(?<=\s)` - there must be a whitespace before...
- `#` - a literal hash
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?!.*[@$#])` - fail the match if there are `@`, or `$`, or `#` somewhere after the `\w+` on the line.

Comment: thanks a lot,I have updated my question, now if I also want to mach a string like this **set #WaitStart <= 13**, how can I modify your regex,I found your regex only match a substring not followed by anything!

Comment: Now I have wrote a regex for myself `\s#\w+(?![@\w\$#_])`,but thank you all the same! Shall I need to vote your answer for the right answer due to your patient?

Comment: I do not understand how `\s#\w+(?![@\w\$#_])` can work for you since it matches in `6. While #AcceleratorPeda l$desddd# <=2` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN3mP9/6)). If my answer proved helpful, please consider upvoting, if it worked for you, consider accepting (these are usual SO rules).

Comment: Ah, I did not get your update. You do not want the `<=` + digits in the match, right? I updated the answer.

Comment: I was battling this in Ruby, and the `[]` were the key to unlock why it wasn't working. (I was pushing forward with `(?!\S)` and so-on)

Comment: @joshfindit Well, I have no idea what you actually need, but from today's perspective, my solution for the current OP problem should be `(?<!\S)#(?!.*[@$#])\w+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN3mP9/15)).